# Erro ao importar pygame no Pycharm

Tags: python, pygame, pip, pycharm

Estou aqui somente porque já faz uma semana que tento de todas as maneiras instalar o `pygame` no PyCharm e não estou conseguindo. Já tentei pela linha de comando e por diversas maneiras, mas quando consigo instalar, aparece um erro.

O erro que aparece quando consigo instalar é este:

> [d:\build\libmpg123\mpg123-1.25.10\src\libmpg123\id3.c:482] error: No
>   comment text / valid description?

Já o outro erro que aparece e não deixa instalar é este:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Rafael/PycharmProjects/exercicios/ex021.py", line 1, in
>   
>       import pygame ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Estou fazendo apenas um exercício simples onde quero tocar um arquivo em mp3. Segue abaixo o código:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('ex021.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.event.wait()
```

Já tentei pelo `pip install pygame`, já tentei clicando na luz vermelha direto no próprio PyCharm, já tentei por `settings - project interpreter`, enfim, acredito que seja alguma incompatibilidade de versões.

Estou utilizando o Windows, Python 3.8.2 PIP 20.0.2 e o `pygame` que estou tentando instalar é o `pygame 1.9.6` Alguém consegue me ajudar, por favor?

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui resolver isso, especificando a biblioteca pygame usando mixer:

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()

mixer.music.load('Hoist.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
input('Agora você escuta?')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simionato, tente baixar o pygame em: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygame

Selecione a opção
pygame-1.9.3-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl

Na pasta de instalação do Python (C:\Users\SeuUsuario\ AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python"versão"\Scripts), coloque o arquivo que foi baixado.

Acesse, pelo CMD, a pasta do Python e atualize o pip com a seguinte linha de comando: python -m pip install --upgrade pip.

Ainda no CMD, digite cd Scripts e tecle enter; Instale o pygame, com o comando pip install pygame-1.9.3-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, ainda não consegui, não encontrei o arquivo que me passou do pygame-1.9.3-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl (no meu caso acho que seria o 64,)enfim, ao digitar cd Scripts, também não encontra nada... Mas tentei isso tudo na corrida hoje, porém, não consegui... Amanha tentarei novamente... Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Grande abraço.

Comment: Quanto a não conseguir acessar a pasta, o seu Python foi instalado via download direto ou pelo Anaconda?

Pode tentar esse abaixo:

v64
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/a5/580578790aa2f8f274855d45b4c89ffb910f1c72ddb754873b2ae8d7fc7f/pygame-1.9.6-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

v32 https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6d/ca/6c54a92efc66ef33e78cb003148c637debd3a85eb44a8d93df19c1f2f9c6/pygame-1.9.6-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui resolver.
Na pasta do seu projeto no Pycharm, exclua a pasta "interpreter" e volte no Pycharm > settings > Project: Nomedoseuprojeto > Project Interpreter e adicione outro "interpreter". E aí é só adicionar o pygame, seja pelo terminal, "cd diretóriodoprojeto...\Interpreter\Scripts > pip install pygame" ou pela interface do Pycharm mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui resolver o problema do 'pygame' no Pycharm 3.8.5. Vá em: File>Sttings>Project:"o nome do seu projeto">Python Interpreter> Em Package, clique em +> agora procure no canto esquerdo da tela que vai abrir na lupa de pesquisa: pygame. Agora é só clicar em install Package. PRONTO!!!

Answer (score -3):

mano, eu passei pelo mesmo erro de instalação do pygame, mas consegui resolver instalando pelo pip.

faz assim:
1) abre cmd como administrador
2) executa o comando pip list
3) se tiver pygame instalado tu executa: pip uninstall pygame
4) e instala novamente: pip install pygame
5) pip list novamente para ver se instalou
6) roda no IDLE do python um código para ver se funciona